# SOAP annotation for path

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need to manage different versions that come in the URL of the Webservice. I'm using a common method in the Webservice for SOAP and REST, and when I tried to get the path in the endPoint class I got the correct path for REST, but not for SOAP(I got a null in this case), does anybody how to get the path in soap?
The url looks like: http://localhost:8083/webService/v1/test and the code is:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ItestgEndpoint", serviceName="testService")
@Component("testEndpoint")
@Path("/webService")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public class TestEndpoint implements ItestgEndpoint{
    @PUT
    @Path("/{version}/test")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @WebResult(name="testResponse")
    public testResponse testEvent(@WebParam(targetNamespace="http://test/web", name="message") 
            @RequestParam MessageClass message,
            @WebParam(name="version") @PathParam("version") String version
        ) throws TimeoutException, EMSException, ValidationException, AuthenticationException {
         logger.info(version);
  }
```

I saw this post [SOAP and REST Webservice with one implementation in Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871815/soap-and-rest-webservice-with-one-implementation-in-java-ee), but it didn't solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP has no "path" like REST has. Depending on the service toolkit you use (CXF, axis, ...) you may need to collect the information in the request that you can extract from the transport mechanism of the soap message. This may or may not be available to you.

Usually, you wire the SOAP service to a path in a configuration. For example in axis, you set the soap servlet dispatcher in the web.xml, same is for cxf. The actual service is then wired in the beans.xml or services.wsdd.

The SOAP handler finds the service by the name of the endpoint and will then send the call to that endpoint which will dispatch it to the right method. The method is in the transmitted SOAP header, not in the URI.

In REST, the identification of the target service/method is in the URI, not in the XML.

So, in my opinion, for SOAP, this is by declaration and the wiring is static, while in REST, you can have the version as a path parameter.

UPDATE: Since everything is possible if you just try hard enough :-) you could rewrite the dispatcher code to allow an extra path parameter on SOAP, maybe the available packages allow some kind of interceptor class, that allows you to rewrite the SOAP header to point to another endpoint, depending on a header attribute that you invent.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried and in the endPoint you can get the path: 
 Message msg = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
 logger.info("path: " + msg.get(Message.PATH_INFO));